# javascript memory question

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say before my webapp starts, I want to create all dom elements initially and store them in some preloaded array.  Something like:

```
for (i = 1...100) { preLoader.push($('<div id="' + i + '" />')); }
```

and then later, depending on the action, I will take the correct element from the array and append it to the DOM.

Now my question is: if I were to later do:

`$(div#i).remove()`

will it also affect my preLoader array, or is it a different reference than the one in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will it also affect my preLoader array

*No, it will not*. Object will be removed from memory, only and only if there are *no ways to access it*, that is no references to it. After `$('div#'+i).remove()`, you can't access it from the DOM, but you can still access it by `preLoader[i-1]`.So you need to remove the object from `preLoader` array **explicitly**:

```
preLoader.splice(i-1,1);
```

Comment: I thought all DOM-related functions (like append) actually take the argument and create a new object in memory for it just for the DOM and then attach it? So that, for example, if after appending to the DOM I do: $('div#'+i).css(width:0), it would only apply it to the element in the DOM, not the one stored in my array since they're different entities. Or do they actually point to the same address in memory and therefore modifying one, would modify the other as well?

Comment: @paulsmith Look, jQuery is just a mechanism for easy-working with `DOM`. In reality there is only `DOM` and `DOMElement`s . So when you are removing `DOMElement` from `DOM` (no metter by using jQuery or smthn else), they won't be removed from jQuery wrappers,that are existed in your `preLoader` array, and which holds references to appropriate `DOMElement`.

Comment: @paulsmith, answering your question: "$('div#'+i).css(width:0), it would only apply it to the element in the DOM". No, it will apply for the elements in your array too. The element attached to the DOM is the same element in your array. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The object in the DOM is the same. If you want to reuse the same tag again you should call

```
$(div#i).detach();
```

From jquery docs:

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

If you use .remove() you will lose events and data associated with the element beeing removed. But even using remove() you can reuse the same element after by calling .appendTo() again.

Example on fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/sKRCF/1
(sorry about the alerts, it's the easy way).